# Ubuntu not detecting monitors via USB-C

Tags: uefi, multiple-monitors, display, hdmi, usb-c

I know that in the past there have been many similar issues but none of the troubleshooting has assisted in my iteration of the problem. I am using a USB-C to HDMI Dual Display Adapter (Wavlink WL-UH510). I am attempting to use dual monitors and extend my screen. The adapter works with my Android cellphone and says it should work with Linux system. My desktop has the following:

- ASUS B660 ProArt Motherboard (1 HDMI Port, 1 USB-C Port Supporting DisplayPort Output, & 1 DisplayPort Input Port)
- i9 12900 CPU with integrated graphics
- Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

I have updated drivers, restarted the system several times to no avail. I have downloaded and run the DisplayLink driver as described [here](https://support.displaylink.com/knowledgebase/articles/683482-displaylink-support-for-ubuntu-now-available). Both screens work individually through the HDMI port. All USBs (including the USB-C in question) are enabled within UEFI on startup.
When I run `xrandr`, this is the output:

```
XWAYLAND0 connected primary 3840x2160+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 620mm x 340mm
   3840x2160     29.98*+
   2048x1536     29.95  
   1920x1440     29.95  
   1600x1200     29.95  
   1440x1080     29.86  
   1400x1050     29.98  
   1280x1024     29.90  
   1280x960      29.82  
   1152x864      29.92  
   1024x768      29.89  
   800x600       29.55  
   640x480       29.85  
   320x240       27.50  
   2560x1600     29.99  
   1920x1200     29.95  
   1680x1050     29.95  
   1440x900      29.91  
   1280x800      29.83  
   720x480       29.25  
   640x400       29.58  
   320x200       26.53  
   3200x1800     29.96  
   2880x1620     29.96  
   2560x1440     29.94  
   2048x1152     29.94  
   1920x1080     29.95  
   1600x900      29.92  
   1368x768      29.94  
   1280x720      29.93  
   1024x576      29.84  
   864x486       29.50  
   720x400       29.51  
   640x350       29.03
```

Please let me know if you have additional questions about hardware or steps taken.

Comment: Welcome to AU. First of all, DisplayLink (TM) has nothing to do with it. The similarity between the old virtual-display-over-USB (DisplayLink) and DisplayPort can be confusing at times but the former has nothing to do with the USB-C alternate mode that brings video outputs, it precedes the USB-C standard and even USB3.0 (the first DisplayLink (TM) devices were for USB2.0).

Comment: You need to check UEFI settings first. USB-C modes may or may not be enabled/disabled in the firmware. Please [edit] and update the question accordingly. You don't need any user installable drivers for the USB-C video output.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Thank you for your response. In the BIOS UEFI, all USBs are enabled, including the USB-C in question. I also found an option to enable dual monitors, which I updated but has not resulted in any change. Is there a specific setting I should be looking for?

Comment: I don't know the specifics of your software so I can't tell. Please consult your user's manual and/or other online documentation.